# OSX Mavericks get tags of a file in c program

Tags: c++, c, osx-mavericks, tagging, xattr

I need to get the usertags for a file in c program.
I am aware of "mdls -name kMDItemUserTags FILENAME" command to get this details. But i need to do it in c code. Is there any way from which i can get the values directly instead of running this command and parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it via the `NSURL` *Resource Key* `NSURLLabelColorKey` which uses an `NSColor` to specify the colour.

Therefore it cannot be done in C *per se*, however you can write an Objective-C implementation file with a C function entry point so it can be called from C (as noted by @Alex MDC in the comments you can use `CoreFoundation` and do it in C directly, but I would always favour `Foundation` where possible as it's easier to use when using ARC).

Given `NSColor` is used to specify the colour, you'll need to create a `struct` to hold the RGB values and translate between that `struct` and `NSColor` yourself.

Something like (untested):

OSXFileLabelColour.h:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct {
    int isSet;          // if 0 then no colour set
    float r;
    float g;
    float b;
} LabelColour;

/* Return 1 for success or 0 for failure */
extern int getFileLabelColour(const char *filename, LabelColour *colour);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}    // extern "C"
#endif
```

OSXFileLabelColour.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "OSXFileLabelColour"

int getFileLabelColour(const char *filename, LabelColour *colour)
{
    int retval = 0;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@(filename)];
    if (url) {
        NSColor *nscolor = nil;
        NSError *error = nil;
        if ([url getResourceValue:&nscolor
                           forKey:NSURLLabelColorKey
                            error:&error]) {
            if (nscolor) {
                CGFloat r, g, b, a;
                [nscolor getRed:&r green:&g blue:&b alpha:&a];
                colour->isSet = 1;
                colour->r = r;
                colour->g = g;
                colour->b = b;
            } else {
                colour->isSet = 0;
            }
            retval = 1;                
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to get colour label for file '%s': %@", filename, [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create URL for file '%s'", filename);
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: You can do in pure C using the core foundation CFURL class method `CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey()`
with the `kCFURLLabelColorKey` key. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Reference/CFURLRef/Reference/reference.html for the reference docs.

Comment: @AlexMDC That is true; however I would always favour Foundation over CoreFoundation where ever possible, given ARC can simplify implementation.  Please add an answer showing the CoreFoundation way of doing it, and we can compare.

Comment: -trojanfoe yes we can achieve this using a wrapper. Even i moved into this now. But one thing is we have to compile this in 10.9+ machine itself because NSURLTagNamesKey in sot available in lower SDK's.

Comment: @user1336309 My code doesn't use that key; it uses `NSURLLabelColorKey` which is 10.6+.